# Object Model Design

Tags: relational-database

I had a question about the best way to handle this type of data.

In my system, I will have many users and many accounts... users are able to belong to many accounts, and accounts will have many users.  I'm guessing the best way to accomplish this is with three tables

> users
>
> accounts
>
> & users_accounts

my question is, when someone signs up for a paid account... where should I store the flag that distinguishes between regular users of an account and account holders?  Should there be an owner flag in the users_accounts table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I assume that one account cannot have more than one user (1-to-many relation)? In that case, two tables would be sufficient:

- `users`
- `accounts`

Where `accounts` contain a reference to a user id. A separate relationship table would be superfluous when there is no many-to-many relation.

Then the question arises: can a user have both paid and unpaid accounts? If so, the flag belongs in `accounts`. Otherwise, it belongs in `users`.

---

Taking your clarification into account, your three tables design is appropriate. The answer to your question then completely depends on how you want paid accounts to work.

- Will a paid user have extra functionality in all accounts? Then the flag belongs in `users`.
- Will any user have extra functionality in a paid account? Then the flag belongs in `accounts`.
- Will a paid user have extra functionality only in paid accounts? Then the flag belongs in `users_accounts`.

---

If every account has only one **owner**, then you should put a user id representing the owner in the `accounts` table.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't clarify.  Each account will also have many users.

Comment: The user wouldn't have a paid and unpaid account persay, but they would be the 'account-holder' so to speak, or an 'account-member'

Comment: In that case, I would stored the flag in the account table.  If the account is paid, all users are paid, right?

Comment: My question is how to determine who is the owner of the account.

Comment: Your third bullet-point is what I'm getting at.  The paid account holder would only have special abilities within the account he's paid for... but he may belong to someone elses account as just a basic user.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I was over thinking it.  You're right.  A simple owner_id in the accounts table should suffice.  Thanks for helping me think this through.

Comment: See my latest edit. If an account can have only one owner, put a user id in the `accounts` table. You can also put your flag in `users_accounts`, but then it's harder to enforce the one-owner constraint.

Comment: So I could do a 'type' column in the users_accounts table that would specify each users role within an account.

Comment: That depends on how sophisticated your type/role system will be. If it's as simple as one owner per account, stick with the user id in `accounts`. If different users can have the same role within an account, then your 'type' column idea would work well.

Answer (score 0):

`Users` table will have only the user related data... name, surname, etc...
`accounts` will have the info of the account... type and any other data...

The key is that `users_accounts` is a relation table between `Users`and `accounts` so it will have any linking data from the `Users` to the `accounts` and THERE you should put the flag because is there when you set the relations.

Comment: there as in the users_accounts table?

Comment: I get confused with the table names... users_accounts is teh relational table and there you should put the flag... The structure should look something like this:

`id - id_users - id_accounts - flag`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `paid` flag to `user_account`.

Example Attributes:

- `user (id, name, street ...)`
- `account (id, name ...)`
- `user_account (user_id, account_id, paid)`

You can tell by the `paid` column if the user is a premium account member or not.